# Junit (or surefire) doesn't seem to be seeing my tests

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using the surefire plugin to try and run some unit tests. At the minute, I basically have the "Hellow, world!" of all unit tests. Here is the code :

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestDefaults {

    @Test
    public void TestOne() {
        System.out.println("A simple unit Test");
    }

    @Test
    public void TestTwo()
    {
        System.out.println("Another little test");
    }

}
```

but when I run :

```
mvn clean test
```

I get the messages :

```
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Skipping execution of surefire because it has already been run for this configuration
```

If I run :

```
mvn clean -X test
```

I don't really see anything else of use than the above messages.

The class also lives under src/test/java/

So I thought this really should have worked.

OS : MAC
IDE : IntelliJ
Build tools : Maven

Comment: Could you also add your pom.xml code on the question?

Comment: Does your tests runs from IDE?